# React native Android build is stuck after upgrading to Pie(9.0)

Tags: android, react-native, mi

react-native run-android is not building the application on to Mi A1 after upgrading to Android Pie(9.0)

I get the below error after running for long time

"What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the android studio to 3.2.1 and installing all the android pie packages solved my problem.